# How can an arrow function receive a parameter as an object which has both properties and default parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, destructuring

Can someone help me understand the following code?

```js
const doit = ({
    left: Left,
    right: Right,
    leftWeight = 1,
    rightWeight = 1
}) => {
    console.log(Left, Right, leftWeight, rightWeight);
};

doit({ left: '111', leftWeight: 2});
```

It seems to be two ways to pass default parameters, and destructuring assignment is involved somehow but how can I break this down to understand it?

## Addendum 1

Ok, it seems as though this is not an issue of default parameters and arrow functions but simply object destructuring:

```js
const { left: Left, right: Right, leftWeight = 1, rightWeight = 1 } = { left: "111", leftWeight: 2 };
console.log(Left, Right, leftWeight, rightWeight);
```

## Addendum 2

This code gives the same result:

```js
const { Left, Right, leftWeight = 1, rightWeight = 1 } = { Left: "111", leftWeight: 2 };
console.log(Left, Right, leftWeight, rightWeight);
```

[Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) apparently has the option to rename the variables:

[image]

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users): https://zaiste.net/posts/javascript-destructuring-assignment-default-values/, https://wesbos.com/destructuring-default-values, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring, https://learnwithparam.com/blog/default-values-while-destructuring-in-javascript/, ...

Comment: You're working with an object passed as the argument, it's pretty straight forward but to simplify it you'd use four arguments left, right, leftweight, rightweight and adjust the function that's all and if you still need an object outputted you can reconstruct it on the return.

Comment: "*It seems to be two ways to pass default parameters*" what do you mean? There is basically a single way to pass default values in destructuring. There is *also* a way to set a default pramter but that's not used here. The code only shows one kind of defaults.

Comment: Yes, it's not a default parameter, it's just a property destructuring default. What is the question that is left?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the links etc., the piece that I wasn't seeing was that object destructuring apparently has an option to give the variables different names with the colon syntax. This syntax looks like (a) key/value syntax, and (b) TypeScript type syntax, and hence it was confusing.